# How to assign inner dictionary to iterates easier

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a nested dictionary but only wanted to assign the inner keys and values to work with. The only way I know would be:

```
wordFrequency = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}}

for word,innerDictionary in wordFrequency.iteritems():
    for fileNum,appearances in innerDictionary.iteritmes():
```

There must be a way without the nested for loops?

I thought maybe something like:

```
for fileNum, appearances in wordFrequency.get(word, {}).iteritems():
```

But would this do something different?

Comment: its based on how you want to use those `key` and `values` , if you need to process them depend on outer keys like `bit` you need this loops but if you want to access to all of this inner dictionary you can use `wordFrequency.values` to get a list of them !

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this a lot, you can write a generator to avoid duplicating the logic. For example:

```
def flatten(x):
    for i,a in x.iteritems():
        for j,b in a.iteritems():
            yield i,j,b

for word,fileNum,appearances in flatten(wordFrequency):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not the solution you are looking for but for what it is worth, I'd like to share how I would write it if I am not allowed to use the nested for-loop:

```
from itertools import chain
from opertor import methodcaller

# I am allowed to use the 'for' key-word only once
for (fileNum, count) in chain.from_iterable((map(methodcaller('items'), wordFrequency.values())):
    do_something(fileNum, count)
```

But as you can see it is way messier/unreadable code and I wouldn't write it this way unless someone threatens to kill me if I used the nested for-loop. I don't understand what's wrong with your nested-loop solution?
Maybe someone has better ideas...

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension to make it a one-line statement, although probably be less readable

```
>>> wordFrequency = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}}
>>> [[(kv[0],k,v) for k,v in kv[1].iteritems()] for kv in wordFrequency.iteritems()]
[[('bit', 1, 3), ('bit', 2, 4), ('bit', 3, 19), ('bit', 4, 0)],
 [('dog', 1, 3), ('dog', 2, 0), ('dog', 3, 4), ('dog', 4, 5)],
 [('red', 1, 0), ('red', 2, 0), ('red', 3, 15), ('red', 4, 0)]]
```

You can iterate through the tuples if you want, as in

```
wfaList = [[(kv[0],k,v) for k,v in kv[1].iteritems()] for kv in wordFrequency.iteritems()]
for word, fileNum, appearances in wfaList:
    ......
```